# Catching errors in computed properties in Vue

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, computed-properties

In VueJS I have a vuex store getter which may throw an error of type `ErrorOne` or `ErrorTwo`.

```js
// myGetter.js
export class ErrorOne extends Error {}
export class ErrorTwo extends Error {}

export default () => {
    if (...) {
        throw new ErrorOne()
    }
    if (...) {
        throw new ErrorTwo()
    }
    return ...
}
```

And in a computed property in my Vue component I am using this getter but I want to handle these errors in a try catch block.

```js
// MyComponent.vue
import { ErrorOne, ErrorTwo } from '.../myGetter'

export default {
    ...,
    data() {
        return {
            errorOne: false,
            errorTwo: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        myGetterComputed() {
            try {
                const value = this.$store.getters['.../myGetter']
                this.errorOne = false            // Unexpected side effect
                this.errorTwo = false            // Unexpected side effect
                return value
            } catch (err) {
                switch (err.constructor) {
                    case ErrorOne:
                        this.errorOne = true     // Unexpected side effect
                        break
                    case ErrorTwo:
                        this.errorTwo = true     // Unexpected side effect
                        break
                 }
             }
         }
    }

}
```

But eslint tells me `[eslint] Unexpected side effect in "myComputedGetter" computed property. [vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties]`.

What is the correct way to handle errors in Vue computed properties in my use case?

Should I move `myGetterComputed` to data and use a watch method to handle updates?

Comment: Side effect here is that you are assigning values in `computed` properties. `computed` should do some calculation or transformation and `return` the result. You should just move the whole `myGetterComputed` into methods (and rename it)

Answer (score 4):

If I am going straight to answer your question I can tell you that eslint is using [this rule](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.md) to warn you about an unintended side effect. As per the eslint-plugin-vue docs

> It is considered a very bad practice to introduce side effects inside computed properties. It makes the code not predictable and hard to understand.

Basically what we need to remember is that computed properties are meant to be used when there's heavy logic associated to how we treat data inside templates. So you shouldn't be updating any properties/data inside a computed property logic.

I would like to help you further if you provide a more detailed example of what you're trying yo achieve

Comment: Ah okay, so eslint is just trying to prevent unintentional errors from occurring even though there may be no issue doing this if it's intentional. I don't have the time to provide a stand alone full example right now, but my use case was for a getter called `marketOrderPrice` which returns the market price of a possible market order and returns two possible errors: `InsufficientMarketError` or `NoMarketError`

Comment: A very simple solution would be if I can catch errors within a watcher but I don't think that's possible in Vue

Comment: @Acidic you can use try catch inside a vue watcher, because it is simply a function handler. Also, you could set a method inside your component as a handler for a watcher.